# Can a echarts formatter function use the existing Cascading Templates functionality?

Tags: javascript, typescript, echarts

We have a chart with a time x axis. We need to tweak how the time labels are formatted in some cases, but for most cases, the very handy Cascading Templates work very nicely in Apache eCharts:

```
    axisLabel: {
        formatter: {
          year: '{yyyy}',
          month: '{MMM}',
          day: '{dd}',
          hour: '{HH}:{mm}',
          minute: '{HH}:{mm}',
        },
    },
```

I would like to do something like:

```
    axisLabel: {
        formatter: (value: number, index: number) => {
          if (index === 0 || index === data.length - 1) {
            // print full timestamp for first and last label
            return echarts.format.formatTime('{yyyy}-{MM}-{dd} {HH}:{mm}', value);
          }
          // and otherwise use the default from above ... possible?
        },
    },
```

I didn't find anything about this in the [options docs](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.axisLabel.formatter).

In fact, `echarts.format` is not included in the [API docs](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echarts), but included in the typescript definition, so I assume it's not internally and can be used by developers ...?

**Addition:** eCharts does a really nice job that it e.g. automatically prints important labels bold - depending on the context:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

And with a formatter function, this gets lost - or I didn't find a way yet how I can keep it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source I found that the formatter function is actually passed a 3rd argument with information about the tick that is missing in the documentation.

I opened [PR !332 to improve documentation](https://github.com/apache/echarts-doc/pull/332)

Example:

```
// Use callback function; function parameters are axis index
formatter: function (value, index, tick) {
    // Formatted to be month/day; display year only in the first label
    var date = new Date(value);
    var texts = [(date.getMonth() + 1), date.getDate()];
    if (index === 0) {
        texts.unshift(date.getYear());
    }
    let label = texts.join('/');
    // apply bold style via rich text for significant levels, i.e. `level > 0`
    return tick.level ? `{bold|${label}}` : label;
}
```